# Windowsphone textblock limitation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I have implemented textblock in Listbox ItemTemplate/data template.  It is databound to "Data"  which is getting read from an xml file. Everything works fine but, the text is getting trimmed in textblocks and a there ia a blank space. I know the reason and it is due to limitations in textblock. Now i tried to use,  Scrollable TextBlock for WP7 from Alex Yakhnin's Blog but I am not able to understand how to implement this in my project?

**C# CODE:**

```
string XMLTagNameBody = "page";

private void ParseHeaderBody() 
{
    XDocument SunderGutkaXMLInstance = XDocument.Load(xmlFileToOpen);

    var XMLBody = from query in SunderGutkaXMLInstance.Descendants(XMLTagNameBody)
                  select new BodyContentClass
                  {
                       Data = (string)query.Element("data"),
                  };
    ListBoxDisplayContent.ItemsSource = XMLBody;
}

public class BodyContentClass
{
    string book;
    string data;

    public string Book
    {
        get { return book; }
        set { book = value; }
    }

    public string Data
    {
         get { return data; }
         set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

**XAML Code:**

```
<ListBox Margin="0,25,0,32" 
         x:Name="ListBoxDisplayContent"
         FontSize="48"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="ListBoxDisplayContentStackPanel"
                        Margin="10"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MainContentDisplayTextBlock"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding Data}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <Image x:Name="dividerImage"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Source="/Assets/MainContentDivider.png"
                       Opacity="1"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Links for Alex Yakhnin's Blog/Scrollable TextBlock for WP7:**

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3af9bc99-2526-49fc-b4a5-4170e12d11ab/do-textblocks-have-a-max-line-limit-if-so-how-do-i-increase-it?forum=wpdevelop
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom control and than it can be added to your project like:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ListBoxDisplayContentStackPanel" Margin="10"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <my:ScrollableTextBlock  Text="{Binding Data}"

           HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="scrollableTextBlock1"

             VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="618" Width="427" Margin="12,-11,0,0" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="MainContentDisplayTextBlock"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"

                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Image x:Name="dividerImage"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Source="/Assets/MainContentDivider.png"
                       Opacity="1"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
```

Where **my** is the namespace of your control.